# Need help identifying IC from Intel Mini PC PCB - top marking "1930 3614564"

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, motherboard, pc, mini

I was looking into a blown up Intel Mini PC PCB (PIPO x8) and saw that a capacitor and a nearby IC were blown. I have no clue what the IC is or was for. Luckily I had a photo before it blew so I know the text on the IC, but could not locate any info on the IC. I suspect that they blew up because of over voltage (bad power adapter). IC said **1930    3614564**.

Please help me ID what this IC does and a replacement for it.

[image: PIC of IC(marked)]

[image: PIC of the Entire board with Chip and capacitor removed]

Comment: looks to be a proprietary P/N

Comment: In the first picture it looks okay to me. Are you sure it's blown? (In the second picture you've removed it.)

Comment: Considering how it connects to that large inductor, it's probably a power supply controller of some kind.

Comment: Trace out the circuit around the chip. It is almost certainly an integrated buck regulator, so even if you can't identify the exact part from the circuit you should be able to substitute another one with the same pinout, or even just use a generic DC/DC converter module with the same output voltage. Note that when these chips short out they often take out sensitive downstream components such as SOC and RF ICs, which may make the board unrepairable.

Comment: @BruceAbbott, You are right, I had traced the circuit earlier, and it was a DC/DC 12V to 1.8V ( educated guess from the circuitry around. There is a Power management IC on the next stage, I had a bad feeling its dead. you mentioned right, its killed everything after, so unrepairable.

Comment: @user253751 The pic was taken before it blew as I mentioned. Its blown for sure, doesnt look that neat now, black and broken at pin 2, Vin (12V).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, After extensive internet guzzling with a friend of mine, we found out that the part is SSY1930MTR DC/DC converter. I also came across that FR9886 replaces ssy1930.

[Data sheet for the FR9886](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/736287/fitipowerintegratedtechnology/FR9886/1)

The pins seem to match and thus i could workout that the output is configured for 1.85V.

But unfortunately I'm unable to repair the board because as @BruceAbbott mentioned, SSY1930 blowing out took out the downstream components.

Posting my findings for others that need this info. Thanks to all for helping.